# Posting photo via Facebook graph no longer working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post a photo using the php-sdk - all was working for months successfully but all of the sudden no dice.

Other functions are still working with the same code base (ie: posting messages to wall) - its just the posting of photos that broke on my side.

```
try {
        $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
print_r($e);}
```

Is dumping:

> FacebookApiException Object ( [result:protected] => Array ( [error_code] => 3 [error] => Array ( [message] => No URL set! [type] => CurlException ) ) [message:protected] => No URL set! [string:private] => [code:protected] => 3 [file:protected] => /locationofmy/base_facebook.php [line:protected] => 818 [trace:private] => Array ( [0] => Array [..............]

From the FB php-sdk lines 818:

```
    if ($result === false) {
      $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
        'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
        'error' => array(
        'message' => curl_error($ch),
        'type' => 'CurlException',
        ),
      ));
      curl_close($ch);
      throw $e;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }
```

This was working for a long time - has something changed on Facebooks side?

EDIT: php-sdk version: 3.1.1

EDIT 2:

```
$tag = array(
                'tag_uid' => 'acct_num',
                'x' => 0,
                'y' => 0
            );

        $tags[] = $tag;

        $args = array(
            'message' => $item_description,
            'image'   => '@' . realpath($temp_path . $tempFile),
            'tags'    => $tags,
            );
```

Comment: I assume it has to do with the '/me/photos' - but don't know why..

Comment: Could you show us what is being sent as $args? Does it pass ` source ` which should be the valid URL to an image with the max width/height of 750px?

Comment: Can you confirm "$temp_path . $tempFile" - the error is no URL, usually that means no real path to image. I suspect, that the images are missing and/or your servers filled up and no local images are saving.

Comment: also, fwiw, catch the error with:  try{ // do fb code } catch (FacebookAPIException $e){  echo $e; }

Comment: @AnnaBillstrom You were right, there was an error with the URL.  Fixed that issue and now its working.  Next step is figuring out WHY that happen and who made the erroneous change.  If you post an answer I will accept, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably that the file doesnt exist, or the file system can't serve it anymore. Can you confirm "$temp_path . $tempFile" - the error is no URL, usually that means no real path to image. I suspect, that the images are missing and/or your servers filled up and no local images are saving. (Yes, this has happened to me before!)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `image` to `source`. I believe this should fix your issue.

The Facebook API requires a `source` field but I did not see anything about an `image` field.

You may also have to pass the actual file contents instead of the real_path (based on the example). Or, alternatively, pass an external URL (based on my understanding of the documentation).

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Example: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/